# Cassandra with ldap intergration

Tags: cassandra, ldap

Using Datastax 5.1 version Cassandra, trying to integrate ldap with it. Added required parameters in dse.yaml and cassandra.yaml but when I try to authenticate ldap user then it keeps failing with below error.

```
[root@ip-11.11.11.11 ~]# cqlsh -u 123456
Password: 
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': AuthenticationFailed('Failed to authenticate to 127.0.0.1: Error from server: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message="Failed to login. Please re-try."',)})
```

Here is the message from debug.log.

```
ERROR [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2019-06-06 05:34:50,842  DefaultLdapConnectionFactory.java:68 - unable to bind connection: PROTOCOL_ERROR: The server will disconnect!
TRACE [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2019-06-06 05:34:50,843  LdapUtils.java:577 - [ldap-fetch-user] ERROR - failed to fetch username: 123456
org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapOperationException: PROTOCOL_ERROR: The server will disconnect!
        at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.startTls(LdapNetworkConnection.java:3986)
        at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.bindAsync(LdapNetworkConnection.java:1373)
        at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.bind(LdapNetworkConnection.java:1293)
        at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.AbstractLdapConnection.bind(AbstractLdapConnection.java:130)
        at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.AbstractLdapConnection.bind(AbstractLdapConnection.java:114)
```

Looks like its not able to connect to ldap, not binding with it?

I am able to connect to AD using ldapsearch and get result for the user from the cassandra node. Also imported the certificate into the keystore and mentioned it in the dse.yaml. Any pointers?

Comment: What are your ldap settings like ? Please edit your question to show us the relevant parameters, and the ldapsearch command as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the certificate chain, after using correct intermediate certificates binding with AD was successful.